# jQuery Click Event for 'body' not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios

So to make click events work on iOS I know that it needs to have `onClick=""` or `cursor:pointer`...

However my click event is on my body (to close the menu) so how can I fix this without having the cursor always be a pointer? I tried @media screen but that doesn't work because if someone has a smaller computer it still has the pointer all the time (and I want it to work for tablets).

I tried `<body onClick="">` with no luck.

My Code:

```
<pre>
  /* Open the sidenav */
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
  }

  /* Close/hide the sidenav */
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }

  $('body').click(function(e){
    closeNav();
  });

  $('#mySidenav').click(function(e){
    openNav();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.hamburger').click(function(e){
    openNav();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  </script>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to detect iOS devices and only set the `cursor: pointer` in those cases.

```
var isiOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
if (isiOS) {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```